# C++11 standard: contradictory definitions of aggregate class & literal class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constexpr

The following are statements from *Lippman, Stanley B.; Moo, Barbara E.; JoséLajoie, e. C++ Primer, 5/e* (which teaches the C++11 standard) -

One of the conditions of an aggregate class is that -

> It does not define any constructors

Definition of literal class -

> An aggregate class whose data members are all of literal type is a
> literal class.

Then it mentions the following contradictory statement -

> A literal class must provide at least one constexpr constructor.

Needless to say, this implies that an aggregate class can & cannot have a user-defined constructor.
Clarifications please?

If possible, kindly also explain why a class constructor can be a constexpr and not a const?

Comment: literals don't have to be aggregates: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, not every literal class is an aggregate class, but this does not negate the contradiction.

Comment: And an aggregate may have default (no argument) and copy constructors.

Comment: @Peter yes, but I'm not sure how does it answer the question.

Comment: I don't see the definition of a literal class in C++11 itself. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_literal_type/ <- "aggregate type OR has constexpr constructor" -- that makes more sense

Comment: @dratenik cplusplus is a bit outdated and not always correct. There is already a link to the same information on cppreference above which should be preferred.

Comment: @dratenik makes sense. thanks.